# kernel submit checklist "Any new or modified CONFIG options don't muck up the config menu"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In kernel submit checklist rule
***"Any new or modified CONFIG options don't muck up the config menu"*** 
does this mean we should not add new or modify exiting config options that appear in make menuconfig options ?

Please correct my understanding ?

Comment: This mean that you are **allowed** to add/modify config options, but should check that config menu works correctly after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you should be careful when adding a configuration option. Sometimes it is not straightforward how a menu is created. For example, you may have the beginning of a menu in a Kconfig file then multiple submenus from other included Kconfig file. That is for example how the ARM multiplatform menu is created:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig#n830